# How to change the text and path of a navigation button?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-router, navbar

I have a navbar component, which has a button that transforming me to path (React-Router) "/NEXUM", But, When I'm transformed to NEXUM, i want to change the text of the navbar and the navigation path, so when I click it, it will bring me to a different path, called "/".

```
 const NavBar = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    const homeToNavigate = () => {
        navigate('/')
    }

    const Navigation = () => {
        navigate('/nexum')
    }
    

    return (
        <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            <AppBar id="bar">
                <Toolbar>
                    <img onClick={homeToNavigate} className="logo" src={logo}></img>
                    <Button onClick={Navigation} id='nexumNavigation'> להכנסת קובץ אקסל ישיר </Button>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </Box>

    )
    
}

export default NavBar
```

This is The nav bar component, The "navBar" component is used in both "HomePage" Component that I'm using and "SpagetiComponent", So as I said, I need the purpose of the button to change, I tried doing it with props, but I was unsuccessful, if you have an idea, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
let location = useLocation();
```

```
<Button onClick={location.pathName==="/NEXUM"?homeToNavigate:Navigation} id='nexumNavigation'>{location.pathName==="/NEXUM"?"go home":"go NEXUM"} </Button>
```